# Checking if a page exists in php. GET and include error catching

Tags: php

I am using the following code to include the correct page into the shell page using $_GET from the previous page. index.php?page= . I have fixed the error for it being blank but still get errors when the user changes what comes after the equals. How would i prevent these errors below from coming up and what could i do to prevent blind sql injection. I am using mysqli_real_escape_string but is there anything else apart from prepared statements. I have tried curl but i couldn't get it to work in this situation.
Thanks in advance.

failed to open stream: no such file or directory

failed opening pages for inclusion

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
 if ($_GET["page"] == ""){
  header("Location:index.php");
 }else{
  $page = $_GET["page"];
  include("pages/$page.php");
  }
}else{
 include("pages/home.php");
}
```

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php What is the difference between 'index.php' and 'pages/home.php'?

Comment: I've noticed a syntax error: You write `GET["page"]` twice, instead of  `GET["page"]`. Your code will not work.

Comment: It works fine. First one to check if page is set, Second to check if its blank. Third to set it too $page @KIKOSoftware index.php is in the parent folder of pages. The main folder holds the surrounding pages. e.g header footer. The pages folder holds what gets changed inside the shell page

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in my comment: It should say: You write `$GET["page"]` twice, instead of `$_GET["page"]`. Note the underscore. And are you saying the visiter sees something different when visiting "pages/home.php" and "index.php"? Or do those pages look the same?

Comment: Sorry i typed the code out from my laptop i can assure you the underscores are in there. Index.php is the shell page and home.php is included into the center of index.php when no other pages are being requested. The header is done to refresh the page back to the home because someone will have purposely tampered with the GET array. i could very easily have changed header("Location:index.php"); to include("pages/home.php");. But it makes no difference it still includes home.php once ?page is cleared. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code can be cleaned up a bit. For instance like this:

```
$page = 'home';
if (isset($_GET["page"]) && 
    file_exists('pages/'.$_GET["page"].'.php')) $page = $_GET["page"];
include("pages/$page.php");
```

There's no need to reload to 'index.php' since you're already there.

Answer (score 0):

The `file_exists()` function checks whether or not a file or directory exists.

This function returns `TRUE` if the file or directory exists, otherwise it returns FALSE.

```
if(isset($_GET["page"]))
{
    if ($_GET["page"] == "")
    {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

    else if( file_exists('pages/'.$_GET["page"].'.php') )
    {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        include("pages/$page.php");
    }

    }
    else
    {
        include("pages/home.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using the OP's code ... now i edited it myself. was just doing that only

Comment: Now after your second change, automatic variable replacement in the string will not work anymore (`file_exists('pages/$_GET["page"]')`).

Comment: Now `.php` is missing in `file_exists()`.